# Parsing "他是…" in this short sentence

Tags: grammar

I wonder if someone could help me correctly parse the following and explain why it should be parsed that way:

> 虽然我觉得他是想象不出来的就是了

Is the speaker saying:

> Though, I think he can't imagine (that)/I think it's unimaginable for him

Or is it more accurate to say;

> Though, I think I can't imagine him (like that/doing that etc)

Comment: bkrs:  就是了 that's all; that's it precisely; that's that,赶不上车, 大不了走回去就是了,给他三块钱就是了,往哪儿走呢? 一直着走就是了!

Comment: is there are second half to this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is quite oral,
`虽然我觉得他是想象不出来的就是了` == `虽然我觉得他想象不出来`
That is:

> Though, I think he can't imagine (it)

As for `Though, I think it is unimaginable for him`, you should say:

> 虽然我觉得这对他来说是不可想象的

And `Though, I think I can't imagine him (like that/doing that etc)` should be:

> 虽然我觉得我无法想象他（是那样的/做了那件事）

Answer (score 0):

What did they say before this? Without knowing what came before, my guess is:

虽然
Despite the fact that
我觉得
I think
他是想象不出来的
he has no imagination
就是了。
it is just as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if no more context provided, then this sentence could be interpreted in two different ways:

1. "他是想象不出来的"means that he is the person that you can not imagine [what he looks like, or what he would do, etc]. If the speaker are talking about someone that at least one of the speakers never met, then this part might have this meaning, and a clearer way to say is "虽然我觉得你想象不出来他[会做这种事|长什么样子]就是了".
2. "他是想象不出来的"==> "他想象不出来XXX", i.e., you think that he can not imagine certain objects or events. This might occur in the scenario that both speakers are familiar with this man "he". A better way to express is "虽然我觉得他想象不出来就是了".

Both of them are possible.